# Finding ethernet addresses with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ip, ethernet

I'm working on an assignment where I have to grab the ip addresses of the computers on a local network and attempt to discover the associated ethernet address using a script on linux.

I'm up to the point where my script gets all the addresses but I'm not sure how to get the ethernet addresses using that information. The assignment specification says that 'ip' and 'ping' may be helpful but I'm not sure how to use them to query the other computers for their ethernet address.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The command `ip` has various options. Try `ip addr` or `ip link`

Comment: I've tried variations of those options but I'm not sure how to use ip to get information from another computer on the network

Answer (score 1):

To lookup MAC addresses you could try `arp`

```
/usr/sbin/arp
```

you may need to provide the explicit path to it if its in /usr/sbin unless you are running as root.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your permission on network you can use **nmap ping scan**:

```
nmap -sP 10.168.254.*
```

or

```
nmap -sP 10.168.254.0/24
```

Above command will scan all the host on the network  10.168.254.0 and will give you IP and MAC both.

This would work only for host which are up/visible and **allow ping** return.
And in your script you shall have to filter the output for mac-ip pair.

You can achieve many solution using nmap, this is the tool for you.

Comment: @user3674840 As the question doesn't have script you are talking about in it. Question will be a better fit for Superuser and not for stackoverflow. So include your script in question.

Answer (score 0):

first you can ping an ip address then use `arp -a`